# Button disapear and code don't work anymore

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy/past one sheet from another excel file.
Nothing hard, I have this fonction (which worked before).

But now it say that there is a problem at the "ThisWorkbook.Activate" line.

How is it possible ? The file can't find itself ?

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer()


Workbooks.Open ("the way to the excel source")

    Sheets("produits").Activate
    Sheets("produits").Range("A1:AZ200").Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("Produits").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: is it a compiler error? or a runtime? what is the error

Comment: In any case, you should just reference the excel objects directly. Don't use `.Select` and `.Activate`

Comment: If your button is not getting copied over then you need to set `CopyObjectsWithCells` to True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace with the following which is faster as doesn't have the overhead of .Select and .Activate. You should also include the workbook name for the range you are copying from or set the workbook you have opened into a variable and use that. You would replace Activeworkbook with the variable.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("produits").Range("A1:AZ200").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Produits").Range("A5")
```

With workbook variable:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("the way to the excel source")
wb.Worksheets("produits").Range("A1:AZ200").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Produits").Range("A5")
```

Comment: Don't need to paste ?

Comment: No. The paste destination is specified by the ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Produits").Range("A5")  The syntax shown automatically pastes. Give it a try. Destination (where to paste) is an optional parameter of Range.Copy method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy If you don't specify destination then it is copied to clipboard, if you do specify, it is copied to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Another function doesn't work :

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim WsDest As Worksheet 'destination workbook to write in
Set WsDest = Workbook("YES").Worksheets("maybe")

Dim WsSrc As Worksheet 'source workbook to match with
    Set WsSrc = Workbook("YES").Worksheets("Perhaps")
```

It worked before, it is the same problem, the file can't find himself.
I tried to replace ThisWorkbook by the full name like in the exemple.. 
before it was :

```
Set WsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("maybe")
Set WsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Perhaps")
```

Comment: It is the same problem, on the same file. I Don't understand why your solution is ok on the first part and not the second.

Comment: What you have above sounds like it should be posted as a new answer with all the info required to reproduce the problem. This area is for answers to the question.